# How to add RecyclerView to a View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view extends `RelativeLayout`, and I want to add a `RecyclerView` in it. But the recyclerView can't be shown.

How to solve it? Thanks!

The code:

***`LineChart.java`***

```
public class LineChart extends RelativeLayout {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    public LineChart(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }


    public LineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }


    public LineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }


    protected void init(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        initInside();
    }


    protected void initInside() {
        View v = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.line_chart_recyclerview, null);

        LineChart.LayoutParams params = new LineChart.LayoutParams(
            getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
        params.addRule(LineChart.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        addView(v, params);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lineChartRecyclerView);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");
        list.add("~~~");
        LineChartAdapter lineChartAdapter = new LineChartAdapter(getContext(),
            list);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(lineChartAdapter);
    }


    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

---

***`LineChartAdapter.java`***

```
public class LineChartAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LineChartViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mList;
    private Context mContext;


    public LineChartAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList = list;
    }


    @Override
    public LineChartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                                  .inflate(R.layout.item_line_chart, parent,
                                          false);
        return new LineChartViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LineChartViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }


    @Override public int getItemCount() {
        return mList == null ? 0 : mList.size();
    }
}
```

---

***`LineChartViewHolder.java`***

```
public class LineChartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView mTextView;


    public LineChartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(
            R.id.text1024);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I know the reason.

```
    View v = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.line_chart_recyclerview, null);

    LineChart.LayoutParams params = new LineChart.LayoutParams(
        getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
    params.addRule(LineChart.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    addView(v, params);
```

Here, `getWidth()` and `getHeigth()` are still 0. So your view will have (0;0) size
To fix this, I'd suggest to replace this part with

```
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.line_chart_recyclerview, this);
```

Let me know, if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, it helps. Thank you! :)

And one more question to ask for advice.

I want to add some rules such as `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT` to RecyclerView and change it's size, should I do this during `onDraw(Canvas c)`?

Comment: Hi, @RockerFlower . You're welcome! Regarding extra-rules&width - I'd suggest to set them right in the xml. To make it "right" and "half-size" - I believe, it can be archive like: inside your RelativeLayout (root one) nest RecyclerView into horizontal LinearLayout:

Comment: <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>